# system loads in GNU screen's hardstatus line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-screen

I use screen a lot on my Linux. I wanted to change the hardstatus line a bit.
I want to add CPU and Memory usage information to the line but I don't know how.
after some searches in Google all I could find was %l option to add system loads.

my line (which is copied) looks like this:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline '%{= G}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{= w}%?%-Lw%?%{= R}%n*%f %t%?%{= R}(%u)%?%{= w}%+Lw%?%= %{= g}][ %{y}Load: %l %{g}][%{B}%D %d-%    M-%Y %{W}%C:%s %A %{g}]'
```

and my screen hardstatus line is like this:
[image]

now what are the three numbers defined ad load ??
and how can I change them to something like `CPU load 28% Mem Load 43%` or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep it short:

The three numbers stand for average cpu load during the last minute, 5 minutes and 15 minutes where 0 means 0% load and 1.0 means 100% load.

Have a look at this [excellent explanation](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages) of the cpu load.

For the second question I'm not sure if you can express the system load with *only one* number in the hardstatus line of screen (I don't think so), but I hope my answer helped a little bit ;-) *Jost

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't heard of the screen command `backtick` since then, this could be your favourite (http://aperiodic.net/screen/commands:backtick).

You can for example define a series of linux ($BASH or sh) commands which echoes your own calculated load value and your own calculated mem-usage value within the `backtick` command.

In this example let's assume that you just want to display the second value of the "load average" statistic given by "uptime" (the 5 minutes statistic).

Step 1:
If your "uptime" output would look like this (with a space at the beginning of the line and 2 spaces before "load average:")...

```
 17:04:06 up 3 days, 21:52, 12 users,  load average: 0.36, 0.27, 0.21
```

... you could extract your value like this into the variable cpuLoad (and get rid of the trailing "comma"):

```
cpuLoad=$(cut -s -d\  -f13 <(uptime))
cpuLoad=${cpuLoad:0:-1}
```

Step 2:
Similarily you could extract your memory values from the output of the "free" command and do some calculations explained in [this](https://www.looklinux.com/free-command-output-explanation-in-linux-unix/) fine article which would end up in a variable named memLoad (abbreviated here by "memLoad=...").

Step 3:
Put it all together and echo your output as you would like to see it:

```
backtick 1 5 5 /bin/bash -c 'cpuLoad=$(cut -s -d\  -f13 <(uptime)); cpuLoad=${cpuLoad:0:-1}; memLoad=...; echo "CPU load ${cpuLoad} Mem Load ${memLoad}" '
```

This will update every 5 seconds the values in your hardstatus or caption status-lines, using the escape-sequence "%1`" in your "hardstatus string" definition.

For more calculations you will need more space which has to be all on one line. So put it in a shell function and call the function from within your screenrc file:

```
backtick 1 5 5 /bin/bash -c '_mySystemLoadScreenFunction'
```

What also **did not work** for me was using $BASH instead of the full path.
This did NOT work:

```
backtick 1 5 5 $BASH -c '_mySystemLoadScreenFunction'
```

Hope, this helps.
Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer of @richard-gantz, here is my solution to also extract the memory usage from `free`

```sh
backtick 1 1 1 /bin/bash -c 'cpuLoad=$(cut -s -d\  -f16 <(uptime)); cpuLoad=${cpuLoad:0:-1}; memLoad=$(free -g | grep Mem | awk '\''{print $3"/"$2" GB"}'\''); echo "CPU: ${cpuLoad} Mem: ${memLoad}" '

# Display the status line at the bottom
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%{.kW}%-w%{.bW}%t [%n]%{-}%+w %= %{..R} %1` %{..G} %H %{..Y} %Y/%m/%d %c"
```

I took his solution for cpuLoad using `cut` but could not get `cut` to work with the multiline output from `free`, hence the solution with `grep` and `awk`. I am posting it here, because it took me some time this solution out, so it might be helpful for somebody.

The memory usage is `used_mem / total_mem` in GB.